# Quickbooks Sales rep Query

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using QuickBooks API to connect with my desktop QuickBooksand import the List id's of the sales reps from QuickBooks to my MySQL database.

Following is the xml code to query sales rep which is already there in QuickBooks but I am getting error 500 that this rep not found in QuickBooks . Even then when I tried adding new rep with same name it again showed me error that this name rep already exists...so i am totally confused why the initial search query didn’t work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<SalesRepQueryRq>   
<FullName>firstname lastname</FullName>                 
</SalesRepQueryRq>                                  
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Please help me to find out the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no way that that Sales Rep exists in QuickBooks.

QuickBooks Sales Rep names are limited to *5* characters. You have *wayyyyy* more than 5 characters here:

- firstname lastname

Are you *positive* that you've created a Sales Rep in QuickBooks, and not something else closely related like an Employee?

Comment: Yes the Sales Rep Type column shows as "Other Name"....so how can i query such data for knowing their List ids?

Comment: nvm...i found out the solution..yes you were right ..infact the Full name here are the initials used and not the actual "name"...thanks

Comment: btw when i edit items in quickbooks via api i sometimes get error "Edit sequence out of date" how can i always keep the sequence number correct before editing?

Comment: Always do a QUERY immediately before doing a MOD. Use the EditSequence value you get back from the query request in your mod request. The EditSequence changes every time a record is updated - regardless of whether it's updated via the API or GUI, so you always have to query for it immediately before doing your mod request.