# Add REP to the invoice - 3070 (string too long)

Tags: quickbooks

I'm gonna add sales rep to the invoice using php quickbooks devkit here.

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

The problem is when processing this request via web connector it returns the 3070 error.

```
20190210.20:08:47 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_getLastError() : errorMsg="3070: The string "Dan T. Miller" in the field "FullName" is too long."
20190210.20:08:47 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_getLastError() : Received error from application: 3070: The string "Dan T. Miller" in the field "FullName" is too long.
```

"Dan T. Miller" sales rep already exist and I can create new REP longer than this string. 
I'm not sure what is exactly happening here. Please advise me.

Comment: can you set the length of "FullName" ?

Comment: @tim I set the string length to 255, what should be the maximum length it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. 
SalesRep FullName field should be less than 5 characters ("Initial" field from Sales Rep List not the "Name" field).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24482320/7981202

I used the name "Dan T. Miller" and that is the reason why I faced that 3070 issue.
"DTM" was the correct field for "SalesRep FullName" on the invoice.